# Hibernate composite element mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping

I have the following relationship: Form --[order]-- Attribute.
One form has n attributes and an attribute can belong to n forms. The relation requires to save an extra property : order.

So I have a class form, a class attribute and a class form_attribute like this:

```
public class FormAttribute{
    Form form;
    Attribute attribute; 
    int attrOrder;

     // getters/setters
}
```

On the Form mapping I am mapping like this:

```
<set name="attributes" table="form_attribute" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" order-by="attrOrder" > 
    <key column="form" not-null="true"/>
    <composite-element class="FormAttribute" >
        <many-to-one name="attribute" column="attribute" class="ExamAttribute" not-null="true" cascade="save-update" />
        <property name="attrOrder" column="attr_order" type="integer" not-null="true" />
    </composite-element>
</set>
```

when I create a new form and associate attributes I expect when, I save, to see the form_attribute table populated. But only form and attribute table is. Is it normal? Do I have to manually update the form_attribute relationship?

Comment: Removing inverse="true" and adding a session.flush() after saving my object does make it work, but why do I have to force the flush?

Comment: I am using spring 3.2.5 and Hibernate 4

Comment: The flush should not have anything to do with it. BTW: better to use annotations instead of xml, that's the new way to go.

Comment: Well still when I do not flush it doesn't go through. And my service method that saves the form is @Transactionnal(readOnly = false). "better to use annotations instead of xml, that's the new way to go" not such a good argument :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, finally it was a bit of a stupid issue. If I do not save attribute first and since there is no set on the attribute side to manage the link between form and attribute, the composite element was not saved. Saving the new attributes first, then saving the form fixed my issue.